# Pass param from server(expressjs) to front Angular2[Angular universal]

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-universal

I have problem with Angular Universal.

I have all url in databases, so i build routers dynamically, like this:

```
this.router.config.unshift({ path: shop.url, component: 
ShopDetailsComponent, data: shop });
```

It works, until I refresh the page(because after refreshing, array with routers is empty), so i want to pass this param from server.
In:

```
server.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.locals = {component : 'ShopDetailsComponent', id: 123}
  res.render('index-aot.html', {req});
});
```

how to pass param **component** and **id**, and how to get this param in angular?